# How to set default home page in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am very new in yii.

How can I set default home page in my site according to user role? what method is used in yii for this.

What i did is, in my index action i render index file. But how can I make it rolebased?

```
public function actionIndex() {
  $this->render('index'); 
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably figured this out by now but didn't post your answer.  Just in case this helps anyone, one implementation is as follows.  I do not know if there is something built into RBAC that does this, but simple enough to implement.

In the file protected/controllers/SiteController.php change 1 line:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            //$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl); change this
                      $this->roleBasedHomePage(); //to this
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

and add this method to the same file

```
protected function roleBasedHomePage() {
    $role='theusersrole' //however you define your role, have the value output to this variable
    switch($role) {
        case 'admin':
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/page',array('view'=>$role.'homepage'));
        break;
        case 'member':
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/page',array('view'=>$role.'homepage'));
        break;
        //etc..
    }
}
```

What you redirect to could vary considerably depending on what type of page you want at the home page.  In this case I use a static page.  If your pages are named consistently you could leave out the switch statement and concatenate the role to the view name within the createURL.

Comment: First, you have lack of ")" in the 2 redirect lines. Then , why you use switch, and duplicate redirect lines? bad code smell.

Answer (score 2):

You can change you view file in your default controller and action according to user type for example:

```
if($usertype == 'user_type1') { $this->render('usertypeview1'); }
if($usertype == 'user_type2') { $this->render('usertypeview2'); }
```

here usertypeview1 & usertypeview2 is the name of your view files under view folder.

Also you can change the layout as well according to your user type for example:

```
if($usertype == 'user_type1') { $this->layout = 'column1'; }
if($usertype == 'user_type2') { $this->layout = 'column2'; }
```

here column1 and column2 is the layout files under layout folder in views folder

I hope this will help you.